# Represent hierarchy in a JSON object

Tags: javascript, json

I need to represent this hierarchy in a JSON object. Can someone help me out ?

```
- John
--- Lee
------ Nash
--------- Tim
------ Nicole
------ Kelly
--- Alice
--- Stanley
```

Comment: Is this a JSON or a JavaScript question? JSON and JavaScript object literal notation are very similar but other than that, JSON is not related to JavaScript. So if you only talk about JSON, you don't need JavaScript. What is the relation between the names?

Comment: So, this example can be given a simple example as the accepted one by DrStrangeLove below-- this is because you only encounter each name once and we assume there is very simple logic consuming the data.

A more robust solution might include UUID/GUID identifiers for each person, the name, and a list type field specifying a parent entity via the UUID/GUID to provide the ability to create a hierarchy  relationships. Things get messy under this strategy for more than 1 parent.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
{
  "name": "John", 
  "children": [ 
    {
      "name": "Lee", 
      "children": [
         {
           "name": "Nash", 
           "children": [{ "name":"Tim"}]
         },
         {
           "name": "Nicole"
         },
         {
           "name": "Kelly"
         }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Alice"
    },
    {
      "name": "Stanley" 
    } 
  ] 
}
```

Comment: is there a way to validate JSON?? Like HTML/XHTML, CSS??

Comment: JSON Validator(online) - https://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 5):

How about this:

```
{
    "John" : {
        "Lee" : {
            "Nash" : {
                "Tim" : null 
            },
            "Nicole" : null,
            "Kelly" : null 
        },
        "Alice" : null,
        "Stanley" : null 
    }
}
```

The relationship, whether it be children or otherwise, is implied by the tree hierarchy.

Comment: Might be better to use an empty table (`{}`) instead of `null`. Possibly easier to handle.

Answer (score 2):

```
["John", [
    ["Lee", [
        ["Nash", [
            ["Tim"]
        ]],
        ["Nicole"],
        ["Kelly"]
    ]],
    ["Alice"],
    ["Stanley"]
]]
```

Comment: This is a recursive representation: each leaf is a singleton [object], each branch is a pair: [object, [children]], each "children" being an array of child (branch or leaf).
This is the smartest answer, since each object can be represented by a string as well as any object.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the accepted answer but I think it's better to make it an array at the top level, otherwise you can only support one value at the root level. This way the whole data structure is also recursive.

```
[
  {
    "name": "John", 
    "children": [ 
      {
        "name": "Lee", 
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Nash", 
            "children": [{ "name":"Tim"}]
          },
          {
            "name": "Nicole"
          },
          {
            "name": "Kelly"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Alice"
      },
      {
        "name": "Stanley" 
      } 
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
{"name": "John", "children": [ {"name": "Lee", "children": {...}}, {name:"Alice", "children": {..}} ] }
```